# discord python bot isn't replying to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my discord bot isn't replying to commands does anyone know why? i also get an error that says discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway

```
token = 'mytoken'

import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('we are logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$info'):
    message.channel.send(f'> i am a bot currently being developed by agent')


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Use a bot instead of a client, indent the `on_ready` block, and don't forget to await async functions. Check the answer below. No need to use on_message, you can instead define `info` as its own function.

Comment: downgrading to discord.py==1.7.3 should work

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bot instead of a client, and don't forget to `await` async functions.
try this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'mytoken'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready!')

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send('> i am a bot currently being developed by agent')


bot.run(token)
```

now try $info with the bot running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use discord.ext.commands instead of discord.client

```
token = 'mytoken'

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('we are logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client:
    return

if message.content.startswith('$info'):
    message.channel.send(f'> i am a bot currently being developed by agent')

bot.process_commands(message)
client.run(token)
```